# Create custom multiselect countries attribute for products

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

For products in the admin, I need to have a custom attribute which contains the list of countries. It needs to be multiselect.

I created a multi select attribute in the admin, left the options blank, and in the database changed the source_model to 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Countryofmanufacture'

This appeared correctly on a product page in the admin, however when selecting one or more countries and saving, the countries do not save.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have done all steps you described, it should work.

The condition to make it works is your attribute has:

- `backend_model` value is `Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend`.
- `backend_type` value is `text` (default value) or `varchar`.
- `frontend_input` value is `multiselect`.
- `source_model` value is `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Countryofmanufacture`

You can run this SQL query to check if all properties are correct:

```
SELECT `attribute_id`, `attribute_code`, `backend_model`, `backend_type`, `frontend_input`, `frontend_label`, `source_model` FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `source_model` = 'Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product\\Attribute\\Source\\Countryofmanufacture'
```

It should show the result like the screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was missing something there. Additionally I found I needed to either clear the cache or reindex the site in order for the save to work (did both at the same time).

Comment: @jaybong Great. Glad to help!